# How use a hline with icimoku base line price

Tags: pine-script

hi i need get baseline price and show with Hline in chart(idont need chart price(close,low...) just i need icimoku baseline price) this is my code

my error:
line 10: Cannot call 'hline' with 'price'=series[float]. The argument should be of type: input float

code:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © WorldNull

//@version=4
study("t_01",overlay=true)
basePeriods = input(103, minval=1, title="Base Line Length")
donchian(len) =>avg(lowest(len), highest(len))
bs = donchian(basePeriods)
bsw=(bs == bs[1]) and (bs==bs[2])
hline(bs)
plot(bs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hline()` can't accept a series types such as `close` or `bs` which change from bar to bar, only a static input value or set value such as `hline(30)`

You can use `trackprice = true` with `plot()`

```
plot(bs, trackprice = true)
```

or use the line functions like this which gives you more control of the style, colour, etc and without having to plot the normal moving non horizontal line

```
f_hline(_price, _color, _style, _width) =>
    _t2 = int(time + change(time))
    var line _line = line.new(x1 = time, y1 = _price, x2 = _t2, y2 = _price, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = _color, style = _style, width = _width, extend = extend.both)
    line.set_xy1(_line, x = time, y = _price)
    line.set_xy2(_line, x = _t2, y = _price)

f_hline(bs, color.red, line.style_dashed, 1)
```

Comment: tanx for helping

Comment: i have one question more, how i change time frame my F_hline to day or 1 hour??